# Send file between 2 Openwrt routers

Tags: router, openwrt

I have 2 TP-Link routers with OpenWRT installed. Two routers are connected by WDS  bridging system. How can I send file from one router to another from ssh session? Please,  suggest me how I can do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1.create a virtual interface and configure ip;
2.bridge virtual interface to wireless interface face；
3.use scp or other tools